# Controlled and monitoring a mobile phone

Tags: android, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to create a python based scritp that controls an android device and monitor it using a raspberry pi WiFi.
The project have gone no where, since I didn't find a liberary that can help me, or many I didn't look hard enough.
If there is any recommendation that I can base my start from, that would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you want to control and monitor ? You could build an android app that exposes an API for external control

Comment: For example the phone signal, accessing the phone photos and messages.

Comment: For the photos and contacts you could google api to retrive them from the cloud (assuming that you've uploaded them automatically from the phone), for the signal part i don't think you can that easily.  Google contacts API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/. If you want full control you can write an android API that will expose the features you want to control or monitor, and then call the API from your python in the raspberry pi.